# Index Notation Question

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, notation

We're busy doing a GR course, and index notation has always been something that confuses me. In particular, is there a difference between the following, and if so, what is it?

$A^\mu_\nu$; $A^\mu{}_\nu$ and $A_\nu{}^\mu$

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Difference between slanted indices on a tensor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/60299/2451) and links therein.

Answer (score 13):

Let's say we start with a general (not symmetric or anti-symmetric) tensor $A_{\mu\nu}$. Note $A_{01} \neq A_{10}$ (and similarly for other combinations). Then
\begin{equation}
A^\mu{}_\nu = g^{\mu\rho} A_{\rho\nu} \neq g^{\mu\rho}A_{\nu\rho} = A_\nu{}^\mu 
\end{equation}
which you could see by explicitly writing out both sides of the not equals sign for a specific value of $\mu$ and $\nu$ (say $\mu=\nu=0$).

If $A_{\mu\nu}$ is symmetric however, in the sense that $A_{\mu\nu}=A_{\nu\mu}$, then $A^\mu{}_\nu = A_\nu{}^\mu$. In that case, out of sheer laziness, some people write $A^\mu_\nu$ instead of one of $A^\mu{}_\nu$ or $A_\nu{}^\mu$. However the notation $A^\mu_\nu$ is just a shorthand and is meaningless if $A$ is not a symmetric tensor.

Comment: To add on, writing ambiguous notation like $A^\mu_\nu$ is bad practice and highly discouraged.